# Persist Firebase user for Node.js client application

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a Node.js command-line interface (CLI) using Firebase 
for authentication with the back end. I want to avoid making the user type their password every time they run a command. Instead, I want to implement a "login" flow that persists a credential to the filesystem that can be used for subsequent password-less authentication until the user "logs out".

Basically what I'm looking for is the [`firebase` JavaScript SDK's](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) "auth state persistence" feature. Unfortunately that feature is not supported for Node.js; calling `setPersistence` with either `'local'` or `'session'` as the mode raises an error "The current environment does not support the specified persistence type."

What's the easiest way to implement that feature "on my own"?

I looked into how the SDK persists the user in a browser and basically it stringifies the user object and stores it localstorage. I can stringify the user object myself easily enough in Node.js (the instance has a `toJSON` method), but I can't figure out how to later de-serialize the string into an instance of `firebase.User`. I see [this function in the source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/780c302fd6da799dafed45345b694a8a8a4a3c78/packages/auth/src/authuser.js#L2253) that looks like it'd do the trick. But that's not exposed externally on the SDK AFAIK.

Comment: A command-line interface (CLI) is local to the machine. CLI is often called a terminal. So, a command line is not intended for end users - it's for admins. Right?

Comment: @RonRoyston It's a CLI for end users, not administrators. The feature I want to implement would be similar to `npm login` if you've ever used that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instantiate the `firebase.User` class from a serialized user object:

**Save user**

```js
const userJson = JSON.stringify(currentUser.toJSON())
// Write userJson to disk
```

**Load user**

```js
// Read userJson from disk
const userData = JSON.parse(userJson)
const user = new firebase.User(userData, userData.stsTokenManager, userData)
firebase.auth().updateCurrentUser(user)
```

Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1874#issuecomment-549085119

Comment: Anyway to do this with firebase v9?

Comment: Read the source, there's an example in the bottom.

Comment: Will this work if the underlying token has expired? Firebase tokens have 1 hour expiry. The API documentation for `updateCurrentUser` says that it will throw an error if token is expired.

So if we use the above logic and the app is quit for more than 1 hour, it will not work.

Comment: @Adi The Firebase ID Token expires in a hour but the refresh token will not expire unless the user is deleted, disabled, or has changed their credentials. I would assume that `updateCurrentUser` takes care of all of that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

In CLI applications that require tokens it is common for these tokens to be stored somewhere on the local machine (often in a "dot" file in the home directory for Linux machines - e.g. `~/.yourapp/config`.

These files can be in any format you want but I like JSON or YAML to store things like this.

In terms of the User object you can easily load the string with the Node.js builtin `JSON.parse(yourStringUser)`.

Within the [firebase-js-sdk source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6b53e0058483c9002d2fe56119f86fc9fb96b56c/packages/auth/src/storage/sessionstorage.js#L117) you can find references where similar is performed with session storage; using the `toJSON()` method to set with a certain `key` and retrieving that value with the `JSON.parse()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm able to save the serialized user into the user's home directory. Calling `JSON.parse` on the serialized user is not enough though because that creates a "plain-old" JavaScript object whereas I need to create an instance of the `firebase.User` class with all of it's fancy methods for refreshing the token and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

[Session management with service workers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/service-worker-sessions)

end users will have Node.js installed locally - and your wanting to build an [interactive Node script/app](https://codeburst.io/building-a-node-js-interactive-cli-3cb80ed76c86) which requires client/token access to Firebase.

> Firebase Auth provides the ability to use service workers to detect
>   and pass Firebase ID tokens for session management.

If you look at how the Firebase CLI itself works, users log in via a web browser then paste an auth code into the Firebase CLI (`firebase login --no localhost`). Then, the user is signed in. So, use a browser and the Firebase Web SDK to collect the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've used the `firebase` CLI (firebase-tools npm package) which uses a browser as part of its `login` workflow. That's super slick, but bringing the browser into the picture only complicates the issue. The browser's web storage is not readily accessible from a Node.js context. That `firebase login` workflow goes through exceptional measures to communicate between Node.js and the browser. (It starts a web server and opens the user's browser window). I need to know what to persist on the filesystem and how to unmarshall it later.

Comment: maybe see [Authenticate with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth). Still, this is a feature of the Web SDK.  ...authentication can be a real time sink, so i'd say think twice before deciding to go custom.

Answer (score 1):

I explored this exhaustively with Google Cloud Platform support, and we determined that this is not possible with the current SDK. FWIW, this feature took me just a few hours to implement using AWS Cognito. There [the CognitoUser constructor](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/47c7cfdd6308b14a1f7673e339680021c2a8764f/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/CognitoUser.js#L83) allows the user to pass their favorite Node.js implementation of the localStorage API.