# Firebase Real-time database not recognizing Auth state

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, electron

I'm having issues accessing one of my realtime databases when rules are set in firebase. I have 3 databases, 1 default and 2 additional. My rules for all are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Everything reads and writes just fine to my "default" database but my other 2 other real-time databases (part of the same APP) don't seem to recognize the firebase authentication and I get "Permission Denied" when trying to access them. Any help is greatly appreciated. I put my code below for how I initialize all the databases.

Was able to read/write successfully when rules were all set to TRUE, so I know I'm pointing to the correct places.

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "someAPIKey",
  authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project",
  storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
  appId: "someAppID"
};
// Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const playersRef = firebase.database().ref()
  const db2 = firebase.initializeApp({
   databaseURL: "https://database2URL.firebaseio.com/",
  }, 'db2');
  const usersRef = firebase.database(db2).ref();
  const db3 = firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://database3URL.firebaseio.com/"
  }, 'db3');
  const gameRef = firebase.database(db3).ref();
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood your code but did you use firebase Authentication to authenticate the user at login page means did u use firebase PhoneAuth and GoogleAuth to authenticate?

in electron application there is some problem to use firebase auth provider and custom authentication to authenticate user because when we use firebase auth provider so electron gives error like this environment is not supported, just enable web storage.

i know why this happen because when authentication process complete then firebase auth system store some data(token and so on) for when user open app again so user will not have to provide detail for authentication that's why so

i found solution follow below answer to solve your problem, best of luck.
[Firebase: Sign in with a token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110378/firebase-sign-in-with-a-token)

Comment: hi Hamid, thank you for the suggestion, but I have no problem authenticating the user in Electron. In fact, all rules I use for my default database work just fine, its only my secondary and tertiary databases that don't recognize the auth.

Comment: Ok bro! and can you tell me how you authenticate the users using firebase auth?

Comment: hi Hamid, I figured it out based off another post somewhere. The databases I initialized I was doing as a seperate 'app', and it wasn't recognizing the auth. But, when I initialized it with off of the original 'app'  `const db2=fbApp.database("https://projecturl.firebaseio.com/"); const usersRef = db2.ref()` 
 all worked just fine! I'll add it as an edit

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I found the solution from another post somewhere, sorry I cannot recall it, but basically the second and third databases were being initialized as seperate 'apps', thus not recognizing the Auth state of the default app. When you initialize secondary, tertiary etc. databases like this (below) all works as expected:

```
 const db2=fbApp.database("https://database2URL.firebaseio.com/"); 
 const usersRef = db2.ref()
```